# Angular - router.navigate() not redirecting to target page

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, angular-ui-router

i'm working on a simple login process where i try to protect certain path unless they are authenticated.

**app.routing.ts**

```
    const  appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
      path: 'add-merchant-admin',
      component : AddMerchantAdminComponent,
      canActivate : [AuthGard]
    },
    {
      path: 'list-merchant-admin',
      component : ListMerchantAdminComponent,
      canActivate : [AuthGard]
    },
    {
      path: 'login',
      component : LoginComponent
    },
    {
      path: '**',
      component: NotFoundComponent
    }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

**authGard.service.ts**

```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import {CanActivate, Router} from "@angular/router";
  import {AuthenticationService} from "../authentication-service/authentication.service";

  @Injectable()
  export class AuthGard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private _authService:AuthenticationService, private _router:Router) { }

    canActivate() {
      if(this._authService.isLoggedIn)
        return true;

      this._router.navigate(['login']);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

**authentication-service**

```
    @Injectable()
    export class AuthenticationService {

      isLoggedIn = false;

      constructor() {
      }

      login(){
         this.isLoggedIn = true;
      }

      logout(){
        this.isLoggedIn = false;
      }
    }
```

When I try to access a **guarded path** like **add-merchant-admin**, the browser keeps loading the page, consuming a lot of memory until it freezes.

These are the details about my app.

**node: 6.10.2**

**os: win32 x64**

> @angular/animations: 4.2.3
>
> @angular/common: 4.2.3
>
> @angular/compiler: 4.2.3
>
> @angular/core: 4.2.3
>
> @angular/forms: 4.2.3
>
> @angular/http: 4.2.3
>
> @angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.6
>
> @angular/platform-browser: 4.2.3
>
> @angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.2.3
>
> @angular/router: 4.2.3
>
> **@angular/cli: 1.0.1**
>
> @angular/compiler-cli: 4.2.3
>
> Dependency Injection is verified.
>
> Component are correctly imported.

I don't know what's going on with this app, normally it should work.

Hope you guys can help me out.

Huge Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify the routes as below,

```
const  appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
      path: 'add-merchant-admin',
      component : AddMerchantAdminComponent,
      canActivate : [AuthGard]
    },
    {
      path: 'list-merchant-admin',
      component : ListMerchantAdminComponent,
      canActivate : [AuthGard]
    },
    {
      path: 'login',
      component : LoginComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'notfound',
      component :NotFoundComponent
    },
    {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: 'login',
      pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
      path: '**',
      redirectTo: 'notfound',
      pathMatch: 'full'
    },
];
```

Comment: Why do you think that the problem is related to the definitions of the routes?

Comment: by default the path is empty at that you are having that route definition.

Comment: yeah but that would result in the app always rendering NotFoundComponent in the first load, not in the app freezing

Answer (score 1):

Change the AuthGuard to this:

```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import {CanActivate, Router} from "@angular/router";
  import {AuthenticationService} from "../authentication-service/authentication.service";

  @Injectable()
  export class AuthGard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private _authService:AuthenticationService, private _router:Router) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
      if(this._authService.isLoggedIn)
        return true;

      this._router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

With `/` as prefix in the first argument of the parameters array of the navigate method you tell angular that the path is absoluth (starts from root).